# In-app purchase using paypal [android]

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway

I am planing to integrate paypal Mobile Express Checkout or Mobile Payment Library with my android application for in-app purchase.
I would like to know,

1. How can I proceed with the integration?
2. Google's "IN_APP BILLING" or PayPal's payment gateway. Which is better?
3. All the transaction fees that are applicable to me as a merchant.

Thanks,

Mith

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend starting with PayPal because as of today it's much more widely used than Google by buyers.  That may change in the future and it may not, but at any time you could always add Google and offer both as payment options just to ensure you have options for buyers to pay however they want.  You might even add Amazon and other options at some point.

PayPal provides a mountain of documentation.  You might want to start with their [SDK library](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index).  Click on the mobile tab and you can download the Android specific SDK.  If you prefer, you can setup simple HTTP POST requests using [NVP or SOAP API's](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api).

PayPal's fees are based on your monthly volume and they start at 2.9% plus 30 cents.  Once you do $3k/mo in volume that will drop to 2.5%, and if you do $10/mo in sales it'll drop to 2.2%.